# How to copy `grad_fn` in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

```
>>> print(foo.grad_fn)
<AddBackward0 object at 0x7f7f9f450710>
```

I want to copy from `foo.grad_fn` to `bar.grad_fn`. For reference, no `foo.data` is required. I want to copy only the `gradient`.

Is this possible? I tried the following and it failed.

```
>>> bar.grad_fn = foo.grad_fn
AttributeError: attribute 'grad_fn' of 'torch._C._TensorBase' objects is not writable
```

thank you.

Comment: Pay attention that `grad_fn` holds "[the function that computes the gradient](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#how-autograd-encodes-the-history)", not the values.

Comment: @Berriel I know, but is there a round about way?

Comment: @JaeyeonBaek did you solve this issue  ?

Answer (score -2):

Actually it is quite easy. You can access the gradient stored in a leaf tensor simply doing `foo.grad.data`. So, if you want to copy the gradient from one leaf to another, just do `bar.grad.data.copy_(foo.grad.data)` after calling `backward`.  Note that `data` is used to avoid keeping track of this operation in the computation graph.

If it is not a leaf, when you have to specify the optional argument `retain_graph=True` in `backward`.

Yet, I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve doing this. I don't get why copying the grad from one tensor to another could by useful. If you tell us more about what you are actually trying to achieve maybe one could give you a more helpful answer.